# Intent Action_Call is not working in android my app

Tags: android, android-studio

Android application I would like to make a phone call(Number from edit text) when user click the button. I have used the below set of code

```
String phone_number = editText.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(phone_number));
            startActivity(intent);
```

and in my AndroidManifest.xml I have added this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />`.

But it is just opening the can add number and no instead of making a phone call.

Comment: Is your app a system app?  Because normal apps cannot be granted that permission.  You can add it to your manifest but it won't be honored.

Comment: I have installed the app on my phone and I have tried to call in my android app. The app is automatically shut down when I press the button

Comment: In Android, there are normal apps and system apps (its actually more complicated, but this is the older simpler view).  Normal apps are installed.  System apps can only be installed by the OEM, or by rooting the phone and installing the app into the correct places in the priv-app folder.  If you haven't done that, your app is not a system app and may not use this permission.  You can put it in your manifest, but attempting to use the permission will result in either an exception or nothing happening, depending on the call.

Comment: Also, system apps may not be put on Google Play.  Normal apps only

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
         @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1000);
                        }
                    }

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone_number );
                    startActivity(intent);
    }
```

You forgot the `tel:` part.