# Intent.ACTION_CALL on Android 13, the phone blocks both sims

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When I make a call using Intent.ACTION_CALL on Android 13, the phone blocks both sims.

Observed only on Android and not the rest of the versions.

Do you have any idea how to deal with this situation?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69522191/6576302

Comment: That doesn't answer my question.
I've correctly implemented everything notified on the link. However, on a phone with two sims, the action of calling in the application blocks both sims.

Comment: That is likely an issue with the specific device model. How many dual-SIM devices have you tested?

Comment: I tested it on 4 smartphones, two running Android 12 and the others Android 13.
On versions 12 and earlier, I didn't notice this problem. On the other hand, on Android 13 (Redmi Note 12 Pro and Redmi Note 11) I do have the problem.